# Can Flash/Actionscript Upload to a Different Server?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to upload a file to another server or pass a file from a Flash object to a script that resides on a different server?

I would like to upload a video to [viddler using their REST API](http://developers.viddler.com/documentation/api/method-videos-upload/). I wish to upload a video directly to them. Is Flash capable of this?

If this is possible, I would appreciate links to tutorials or existing code I can use to make this.

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Flash runtime is capable of this, at least Player 9 and later with AS3. However, the big roadblock is security. The server must export an XML file `crossdomain.xml` which will be read by the player, and its contents determine whether a request succeeds. See [here](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex:Accessing_Data#Using_crossdomain.xml_files) for more information.

Comment: Damn it! That is what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: But you could implement a "go between" on your own server that would take the video from Flash and then do the rest of the work with the viddler api.  This is the easiest way to get around the crossdomain.xml issue.